# Sum value in while loop in pl./sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, while-loop, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to sum the values ​​until the user enters 0 but i have error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jHbD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shEW4.png)

Answer (score 1):

That would be something like this:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     n    NUMBER;
  3     var  NUMBER := 0;
  4  BEGIN
  5     n := &par_input;
  6
  7     WHILE (n <> 0)
  8     LOOP
  9        var := var + n;
 10        n := n - 1;
 11     END LOOP;
 12
 13     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (var);
 14  END;
 15  /
Enter value for par_input: 5
old   5:    n := &par_input;
new   5:    n := 5;
15

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Aha; that's not what you wanted, after all - you want to loop over and over again, until user enters `0`.

Bad news for you - PL/SQL doesn't work that way, it is not *interactive*.

Comment: ok, so this exercises will be not working?

Comment: Not in PL/SQL; try other programming language.